# call OnClientClick and Onclick together in c# Button Event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

I have a Asp.Net c# application in which, having Logout Button on mAsterpage.

I am trying to alert confirmation window on click of LogOut. If i choose Yes, then I will redirect it into Log-in Page.

So I have tried below. OnClient Click I called below JavaScript Function.

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

On Button Click I have wriiten Below code.

```
         protected void ImgbtnLogOut_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                Session.Clear();
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogoutURL"].ToString());
                //Server.Transfer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogoutURL"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Nothing
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error Unable to evaluate Expression, The code is Optimized....error in below line. And Page is not being redirected to required page.

```
                Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogoutURL"].ToString());
```

can anyone please suggest, how can i achieve that.

Comment: have you tried moving your Session.clear(); and Session.Abandon(); to logout page (i.e after redirect) ?

Comment: Yes I have tried it. But Same Result.

Answer (score 1):

This confirm box help you to get correct response with having Ajax.

java script code for geting confirm value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Do you want to proceed continue ?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    </script>
```

On C# Code for geting exect data.

```
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
          string[] Value_Confirm = confirmValue.Split(',');
          if (Value_Confirm[Value_Confirm.Length-1] == "Yes")
          {}
```

or check here : http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1070495/Ask-yes-no-cancel-window-in-csharp#answer6

Comment: this example shows you to trigger Confirmation using JavaScript and Catch confirmation on C# page.

Comment: if You tried Like <asp:Button id="ImageButton1" runat="server"  onclientclick="return Confirm();" onclick="btn_Click"  />  then you need a return type JS function to execute C# onclick function.